# Ember array: no render on `removeObject`

Tags: javascript, data-binding, ember.js

I have an `Ember.ArrayProxy` created like this:

```
Em.ArrayProxy.createWithMixins(Em.Array, Em.MutableArray, Em.SortableMixin, {
  content         : Em.A(arr),
  sortProperties  : properties,
  sortAscending   : fn ? fn : void(0)
}).reopen({
  isEmpty: function(){
    return this.get('length') < 1;
  }
});
```

Data-binding works pretty well when i use `pushObject` or `sortBy` on array. But i have no updates in html when I use `removeObject` on this array. How could i fix that?

My Ember:

```
DEBUG: -------------------------------
DEBUG: Ember      : 1.7.1+pre.c1ec09ad
DEBUG: Ember Data : 1.0.0-beta.9
DEBUG: Handlebars : 1.3.0
DEBUG: jQuery     : 2.0.3
DEBUG: -------------------------------
```

---

**UPD:**

I noticed very strange behaviour when removing objects from the list:
[image: console output]

There is my simpified template in `templates/order/list.handlebars`:

```
<ul class="scrollable_list">
  {{#each group in orders}}
    <li class="group">
      <div class="group_title">
        Orders at {{format_date group.date f="DD.MM.YYYY"}}
        <div class="label">{{group.count}}</div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <ul>
    {{#each order in group.orders}}
      <li {{bind-attr class=':order order.is_mine order.is_claimed'}}>
        {{#link-to 'orders.group.show' controller.group order}}
          {{partial 'order/item'}}
        {{/link-to}}
      </li>
    {{/each}}
    </ul>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

Object `orders` is `ArrayProxy` of `Ember.Object`. Array is created by `this.create_sortable_array`. Each object in array has this structure:

```
Em.Object.create({
  date    : date,
  time    : date.getTime(),
  orders  : this.create_orders_array()
})
```

Property `orders` is `ArrayProxy` too. Each item is `DS.Model` instance.

Methods:

**this.create_orders_array**:

```
create_orders_array: function(){
  return this.create_sortable_array([], ['id'], true, function(a, b){
    a = Number(a);
    b = Number(b);
    return a > b ? 1 : -1
  });
}
```

**this.create_sortable_array**:

```
create_sortable_array: function(arr, properties, desc, fn){
  desc = (typeof desc == 'undefined' || desc == null) ? false : desc;
  fn   = fn || void(0);
  return Em.ArrayProxy.createWithMixins(
    Em.MutableArray,
    Em.MutableEnumerable,
    Em.SortableMixin, {
      content         : Em.A(arr),
      sortProperties  : properties,
      sortAscending   : fn ? fn : void(0)
    }).reopen({
      isEmpty: function(){ return this.get('length') < 1 }
    });
}
```

Template will be rendered in `{{outlet orders}}` by router:

```
App.OrdersRoute = App.AppRoute.extend({
  renderTemplate: function(){
    this._super()
    this.render('order/list', into: 'orders', controller: 'orders')
    this.render({'order/show', into: 'orders', outlet: 'main_view'})
    this.render('order/smart_search', into: 'application', outlet: 'smart_search', controller: 'orders')
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with third-party lib that replace `removeAt` method of `Array.prototype` with it's own method. So in case when Ember removes elements from array it uses it's own `removeAt` which was replaced with another one. In this case some Ember hooks were not invoked and mutation mechanism was unable to detect any changes. Thanks all for help and suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's working fine to me.  It's likely you aren't removing the item from the list at all.

```
var arr = [{a:'saf'},{a:'fdsa'},{a:'asd'}];
var foo = Em.ArrayProxy.createWithMixins(Em.Array, Em.MutableArray, Em.SortableMixin, {
  content         : arr,
  sortProperties  : ['a'],
  sortAscending   : true
}).reopen({
  isEmpty: function(){
    return this.get('length') < 1;
  }
});


App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    Em.run.later(function(){
      foo.removeObject(foo.objectAt(1));
    },2000);
    return foo;
  }
});
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/bufoca/1/edit

Comment: Thanks for your example. I'm doing exactly same things with my array. It looks like my app structure somehow affects behaviour of `ArrayProxy`.

Comment: Can you add the template?

Comment: I'm curious if it's your UL outside of the LI

Comment: Nope. Checked this out, no effect.

Comment: Why there is `undefined` item in array after `removeObject`? (see screenshot in question)